# how to use log4j logger declared in Java side from a dll

Tags: java, dll, log4j, jna

We are using a dll with JNA in our java project. We would like the C code to also log to our log4j log files, is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Not easily, really. I can think of a few ways

- call a Java program within your C code that just calls log4j (slow, you have to load up Java for each logging call)
- leave a Java process running that accepts log requests (communicate with the process using one of the options here [Good alternative to shared memory IPC for Java/C++ apps on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904492/good-alternative-to-shared-memory-ipc-for-java-c-apps-on-linux))
- use GCJ to natively compile a Java program that calls log4j, then link it to your C program