# Python data passing

Tags: php, python

I need exchange data between python daemon (cluster nods send data to this daemon) and php script (apache) which, is accessed by webbrowsers. What do you recommend as technology which could establish some connection between them. Both, python daemon and apache/php is on the same machine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to do is called [IPC (inter process communication)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Since these are common Linux applications I am going to refer you to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281204/which-linux-ipc-technique-to-use) which recommends [Unix Domain Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket).

For PHP look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/transports.unix.php) and for Python look [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/socket/uds.html).

Comment: what do you think about twisted ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want things to be synchronous use a named socket(Amazing feature on Unix systems.)

If you want things to be asynchronous use pickle(there is a php version of it too.)