# Design traces/logs for speed critical system

Tags: c++, design-patterns, logging, architecture

Suppose we have systems which are speed critical (like for example statistics/analytic's,socket programming etc), how do we design the traces and logs.

To be more specific, logs and traces generally reduce the performance (even if we have a switch off mechanism or verbose extension mechanism). In such scenarios, is there any reference guideline on how to 'put' logs/traces so that when the issue occurs (especially at production site) developer/post production team are able to pin-point the actual issue.

PS: I come from background where such applications are developed in C/C++ (run on Linux)

Comment: i guess async logging if you can afford to lose some entries; or something like disruptor from lmax, if you absolutely need consistency

Comment: In case you are meaning logging with another thread, I am aware of that process. However, at times, even these will act as a drag. Wanted to know if there are any other "better" mechanisms to handle logging/tracing.

Comment: Are you looking for a system that adds as little overhead as possible in the case when there is nothing to log? Or are you looking for a way to minimise the overhead of actually writing to the log? If the latter, do the messages tend to cluster together with long gaps in between, or is there a more serious total throughput issue?

Comment: Let me put it the other-way round. I already have system (without inter-module trace, logs) supporting X speed in production environment. Now I am trying to find a way to add logs (all over the system) and traces and trying to minimize the degradation of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accumulate logs inside a buffer which you can describe and implement using [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial). You can have a different thread periodically(every 5minutes) empty this buffer to disk or sending it through a [UNIX domain socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) (or other [Linux IPC mechanisms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281204/which-linux-ipc-technique-to-use)) to a daemon that listens and writes them to a persistent DB or simply writes them to disk.

If you don't want to hit the disk on the machine that produces logs, you can send them to a different machine through a [regular socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets) and write them to disk on that machine.

If you are aggregating logs from multiple machines, consider using [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) or [CrossRoads](https://github.com/crossroads-io/libxs) as message queues to pass your logs through the network to a machine where they are stored persistently. You can find some information about [using 0MQ in conjuction with Google Protocol Buffers here](http://www.dotkam.com/2011/09/09/zeromq-and-google-protocol-buffers/).