# Dask array to HDF5 parallel write fails with multiprocessing scheduler

Tags: hdf5, h5py, dask

Dask being a well documented scalable library for parallel processing, using graph based workflows is extremely useful in writing many applications that have inherent parallelism associated with them. However while parallel writing to hdf5 files being concerned it is rather difficult especially while using multiprocessing scheduler. The following code works fine if default multi-threaded scheduler is used,

```
x = da.arange(25000, chunks = (1000,))
da.to_hdf5('hdfstore.h5', '/store', x)
```

But if you set multiprocessing  scheduler globally:

```
dask.set_options(get=dask.multiprocessing.get)
```

and again run the code,

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
```

The multithreded scheduler is ok, but it is too slow while reading from a single large csv file and converting it to hdf5 file. With the multiprocessing scheduler its fast and able to use all CPUs in maximum load, but the hdf write fails with the mentioned error (the hdf5 files support simultaneous write access with h5py mpi driver, i think). If you directly do

```
x.compute()
```

everything is fine but it loads the entire data into memory, that is not it is so well with large arrays and files. Does anybody came across such scenarios? Please do share valuable suggestions..

Dask version '0.13.0' on a conda virtual env

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with this code is that it writes simultaneously different chunks of data to same hdf5 file when you using multiprocessing scheduler.

As far as I know, HDF5 format supports [HDF5 SWMR](http://Single-Writer%20/%20Multiple-Reader%20(SWMR)). So when 1 Python process have the right to write 1 chunk, it prevent other process to write simultaneously, by locking mechanism.

If you want simutaneous write, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34913236/4353359) could help.