# Passing pointer to an array in program args

Tags: c, memory, sharing

Let's assume we have 2 programs written in C, one program allocates memory with malloc and launches the second program passing the address of allocated memory and size as arguments.

Now the question, is it possible for the second program to cast the first argument to a pointer and read/write to that memory. Why, why not?

For the sake of simplicity assume Linux as the underlying OS.

Comment: No, not in a form it is stated. Two processes are living in their own virtual address spaces.

Comment: Do some research about *shared memory*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because on modern operating systems processes running in user mode see [Virtual Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). The same virtual address will translate to a different physical address or page file location between processes.

Fortunately, most operating systems do have APIs that allow for inter-process communication, so you can research those methods.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281204/which-linux-ipc-technique-to-use) seems to be a good place to start, since you claim to be working on Linux.