# Pipe numpy data in Linux?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, numpy, pipe

Is it possible to pipe numpy data (from one python script ) into the other?

suppose that `script1.py` looks like this:

`x = np.zeros(3, dtype={'names':['col1', 'col2'], 'formats':['i4','f4']})`

`print x`

Suppose that from the linux command, I run the following:

`python script1.py | script2.py`

Will `script2.py` get the piped numpy data as an input (stdin)? will the data still be in the same format of numpy? (so that I can, for example, perform numpy operations on it from within `script2.py`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, data is passed through a pipe as text. You'll need to serialize the data in `script1.py` before writing, and deserialize it in `script2.py` after reading.

Comment: A quick-and-dirty way to do the serialization is to use the python `repr` function. Replace `print x` with `print repr(x)` in script1.py and then have script2.py call `eval` to de-serialize the output of script1.py

Comment: Thank you guys. I have a numpy array that needs to be written to a binary file, and I just thought piping would make the whole process faster (i.e, one process computes, one process writes). Do you have any other ideas to make this work faster?

Comment: `mmap` makes the world go 'round.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the `save` and `load` functions. I don't think they would object to being passed a pipe instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033799/how-do-i-pass-large-numpy-arrays-between-python-subprocesses-without-saving-to-di).

If you're willing to use the `subprocess` module, you can share memory between processes to pass numpy arrays rapidly. If not, I've found saving to a file beats the pants off of piping, probably because converting the array to a string is so slow.