# Python multiprocessing struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multiprocessing, mmap

I'm creating a lookup dictionary with the help of other dictionaries. 
I have 32 cores and 64GB RAM instance where I'm running it.
`names` is a huge numpy array with around `28184057` elements. When I try to apply `pool.map` on 'names', I get the following error:

```
struct.error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

This is my code:

```
pool = mp.Pool(32)
uni_lookup = pool.map(self.create_lookup_dict, names)
pool.close()
```

And `create_lookup_dict` contains the following code:

```
def create_lookup_dict(self, word):
    lookup_word_level = {word: list(set(i[0] for i in self.groups.items() \
                                if word in i[1]))}
    final = []

    if self.tag_dict.get(word, 0) is 0:
        print("No tag")
        return (word, lookup_word_level[word])
    if self.secondary_category_tag_dict.get(word, 0) is 0:
        print("No secondary category tag")
        return (word, lookup_word_level[word])
    for i in lookup_word_level[word]:
        if self.tag_dict[i].intersection(self.tag_dict[word]) and \
        self.secondary_category_tag_dict[i].intersection(self.secondary_category_tag_dict[word]):
            final.append(i)
    return (word, final)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: which line is the error coming from

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh pool.map

Comment: I would suggest you check if the create_lookup_dict works independently, and then try putting . it in pool.map also look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh It takes really long time without pool.map

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Let me check `pool.imap`, it seems promising

Comment: Where is `dish_lookup_word_level` coming from?

Comment: @ChatterOne my bad, it was lookup_word_level

Comment: Can you please add the full traceback?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21139911

Comment: This one can be useful too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776486/python-struct-error-i-format-requires-2147483648-number-2147483647?rq=1

Looks like its a problem about the size of data, returned from pool.map. But I still can't figure out how to solve it.