# Python read image to numpy array with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing

I am working on a python program which read a lot of images in batches (let's say 500 images) and store it in a numpy array.

Now it's single thread, and IO is very fast, the part which take a lot of time is creating numpy array and doing something on it.

By using multiprocessing module, I am able to read and create the array in other process. But I am having problem let the main thread access those data.

I have tried:

1: Using multiprocessing.queues:  Very slow, I believe it's the pickle and unpickle waste a lot of time. Pickling and unpickling a large numpy array take quite some time.

2: Using Manager.list():  Faster than queues, but when try to access it in main thread, it 's still very slow. Even just iterate over the list and do nothing takes 2 seconds per item.
I don't understand why it take so much time.

Any suggestions ? Thanks.

Comment: how much memory does one batch of images take? If its a lot, think about using += and stuff like that to overwrite memory-parts, since A = A + B takes a lot more time than A+=B, when A and B become large (the memory layout becomes more important when your arrays are Huge)

Comment: @usethedeathstar Each of the batch will take about 300 MB. Thanks for your tips, I have already avoided operation like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I have to answer my own question.

The problem I was facing could be solved by using shared memory with numpy.

More details could be found at

[Use numpy array in shared memory for multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing)

The idea is basically create the shared memory in the main process, and assign the memory to a numpy array. Later in other process, you can either read from it or write to it.

This approach works pretty well for me, it speeds up my program by a factor of 10.

Because I am processing a large amount of data and pickling is not an option for me.

The most critical code is :

```
shared_arr = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, N)
arr = tonumpyarray(shared_arr)
```