# multiple processes - python - simple loop with multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing, convolution

New to multiprocessing and I can't get my head around the documentation. How can I run a function of this form across multiple processes? Here is my attempt. I want to **run a convolution** (of start with other) **through multiple processes** for speed.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array 
import numpy as np
import scipy

A = np.ones((10,10,4))
B = np.random.rand(10,10)

def loop(i):
     C[:,:,i] = scipy.ndimage.convolve(A[:,:,i],B)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     C = Array('i',np.zeros((10,10,4)))
     arr    = Array('i',range(4))
     for i in arr:
        p = Process(target = loop, args=i)
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

Current error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 11, in 
>       y_test = Array('i',np.zeros((10,10,4)))
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/**init**.py", line 260, in
>   Array
>       return Array(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer, **kwds)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 115,
>   in Array
>       obj = RawArray(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 89,
>   in RawArray
>       result.**init**(*size_or_initializer)
>
> TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

y_test would be the ouput

Comment: What is your code currently doing?

Comment: You might want to start here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing

Comment: that shows you how to correctly create the array which seems to be your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending line is

```
y_test = Array('y_test',np.zeros((10,10,4)))
```

It is plain wrong. Documentation says for `multiprocessing.Array`

> multiprocessing.Array(typecode_or_type, size_or_initializer, *, lock=True)
>   
> ...
>   typecode_or_type determines the type of the elements of the returned array: **it is either a ctypes type or a one character typecode** of the kind used by the array module...

The error just says that `y_test` is not a know type.

Anyway, you are not taking the problem the right side.

Because a `multiprocessing.Array` is an array of primitive types stored in shared memory. Here, you could easily build such an array through the `flat` iterator of the numpy array:

```
y_test = Array('d', np.zeros((10,10,4)).flat)
```

y_test is now a shared memory array of 400 doubles

Let us forget the multiprocessing for a while. You could process it that way:

```
for i in range(r):
    npi = start[:,:,i] + i
    y_test[10*10*i:10*10*(i+1)] = npi.flatten()
```

You could now convert it back into a numpy array:

```
resul = np.array(y_test).reshape((10,10,4), order = 'f')
```

The interesting point here is that each processing of a 10x10 array access a different part of the shared memory: we can build it in different processes

```
def process(a, i):
    npi = start[:,:, i] + i    # computes a numpy array
    a[10*10*i:10*10*(i+1)] = npi.flatten()  # stores it in shared memory

def main():
    y_test = Array('d', np.zeros((10,10,4)).flat) # initializes shared memory
    processes = []
    for i in range(4):  # uses 4 processes, one per each 10x10 array
        p = Process(target = process, args = (y_test, i))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
        print("Start", i, p.pid)  # to be sure the processes were started
    for i in range(4):
        p.join()        # join child processes
        print("Join", i, p.exitcode)
    resul = np.array(y_test).reshape((10,10,4), order='f') # rebuild the final numpy array
    print(resul)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

### The Exception

You get an exception here, because the first parameter of Array(...) needs to be a valid `ctype` like `c_bool`, `c_int`, ..., or a single character representing such a type like `'i'`. 'y_test' is not a valid ctype. It seems you put in variable names, instead of their types.

Try this, if you want to use integers here:

```
y_test = Array('i', np.zeros((10,10,4)))
```

Take a look at [the Array documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array) for more details on how the Array works. There is also a [list of valid type codes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#module-array) you can use.

### Additional thoughts, parallel execution

Also, keep in mind, that the process will just run the function `loop` with the arguments you provide. You provide two Arrays, but it seems that the loop function needs an Array and an integer as parameters. When you want to run multiple instances of the loop function with different values for i, you can create multiple Process instances and give them each a different value as parameter, like this:

```
p1 = Process(target = loop, args = (y_test, 1))
p2 = Process(target = loop, args = (y_test, 2))
```

Each process will run the loop function with a different parameter. You could also put this in a loop, to iterate over your `arr` to process every value in arr, which - I think - is what you want here.

Comment: i get an error: 'TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted into Python Scalars' originating from the y_test initialization