# Python How to share a List array between two scripts using mmap but without using files?

Tags: python, subprocess, mmap

How can I share a list **between two python scripts** using `mmap` but **without using files**?

My first python script calls the other using `subprocess.Popen(["python","child.py"])`

I have to call 10 different subprocess and don't want to use a file as it will increase I/O time which is not desirable.

Each of my subprocess will modify this list variable created in the parent process.

Note: I don't want to use `multiprocess` or `threads` and require the solution using `subprocess.Popen` only.

Comment: Do you expect two way changing of the list, I.e. should main process know about list changes in subprocesses and vice versa?

Comment: Yes.
The parent will initialize the list. Child will modify it. Parent will print the updated list.

Comment: Do you specifically need to use mmap? Otherwise you can use [multiprocessing's Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes)

Comment: @SiHa so far I tried using files and pickle library but that was increasing my I/O time and hence I wanna shift to mmap

Comment: I think the base question here is: What have you tried so far? Where is your problem, where does your code not work. You should not expect sombody to place a general tutorial for `mmap` as an answer. And if you have a question/problem why ruling out the obvious `multiprocess`. Sounds like "Help me but only in the way I want you to help me".

Comment: @Pynchia please read my post completely.

Comment: @jochen I read online the difference between subprocess and multiprocess and found subprocess to suit my other needs also when compare to multiprocess. I requested specifically for subprocess because otherwise post would have become vast. If it's like I am asking you to help me the way I want it only then it's cause i've read about other ways. I simply wanted to keep this post to the point.

Comment: then this looks like an [XYproblem](http://xyproblem.info/). What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are others facing this too

Comment: related (share array without copying): [Use numpy array in shared memory for multiprocessing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7908612/4279)