# How to implement a reduce operation in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, reduce

I'm an expert parallel programmer in OpenMP and C++. Now I'm trying to understand parallelism in python and the `multiprocessing` library.

In particular, I'm trying to parallelize this simple code, which randomly increment an array for 100 times:

```
from random import randint
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

def random_add(x):
    x[randint(0,len(x)-1)]  += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Serial")
    x = np.zeros(8)
    for i in range(100):
        random_add(x)
    print(x)

    print("Parallel")
    x = np.zeros(8)    
    processes = [mp.Process(target = random_add, args=(x,)) for i in range(100)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    print(x)
```

However,this is the following output:

```
Serial
[  9.  18.  11.  15.  16.   8.  10.  13.]
Parallel
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
```

Why this happens? Well, I think I have an explanation: since we are in multiprocessing (and not multi-threading), each process as his own section of memory, i.e., each spawned process has his own `x`, which is destroyed once `random_add(x)` is terminated. As conclusion, the `x` in the main program is never really updated.

Is this correct? And if so, how can I solve this problem? In a few words, I need a global reduce operation which sum the results of all the `random_add` calls, obtaining the same result of the serial version.

Comment: You are correct in your diagnosis. See [some workarounds](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) in the multiprocessing library.

Comment: sub-process get a copy of your variable `x` but not the original one. So this is a common question about sharing variables in multiprocessing. Just search it as there is a looooot of information existed.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. This also means that if `x` is potentially big, the code is gonna take forever? Just to understand the process :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use shared memory objects in your case:

```
from random import randint
import multiprocessing as mp

def random_add(x):
    x[randint(0,len(x)-1)]  += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Serial")
    x = [0]*8
    for i in range(100):
        random_add(x)
    print(x)

    print("Parallel")
    x = mp.Array('i', range(8))
    processes = [mp.Process(target = random_add, args=(x,)) for i in range(100)]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    print(x[:])
```

I've changed numpy array to ordinal list for the purpose of clearness of code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I have an `Array()` of numpy arrays? So `x[randint(0, len(x)-1]` is actually a `numpy.array`. I think that this will be safe, but a second opinion is always useful :D

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing) about numpy arrays and shared memory