# multiprocessing with Xarray and Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-xarray

So I am trying to implement a solution that was already described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing), but I am changing it a bit. Instead of just trying to change the array with operations, I am trying to read from a NetCDF file using xarray and then write to a shared numpy array with the multiprocessing module.

I feel as though I am getting pretty close, but something is going wrong. I have pasted a reproducible, easy copy/paste example below. As you can see, when I run the processes, they can all read the files that I created, but they do not correctly update the shared numpy array that I am trying to write to. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
import ctypes
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp
import xarray as xr

from contextlib import closing

import numpy as np

info = mp.get_logger().info


def main():

    data = np.arange(10)

    for i in range(4):
        ds = xr.Dataset({'x': data})
        ds.to_netcdf('test_{}.nc'.format(i))

        ds.close()


    logger = mp.log_to_stderr()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create shared array
    N, M = 4, 10
    shared_arr = mp.Array(ctypes.c_float, N * M)
    arr = tonumpyarray(shared_arr, dtype=np.float32)
    arr = arr.reshape((N, M))

    # Fill with random values
    arr[:, :] = np.zeros((N, M))
    arr_orig = arr.copy()

    files = ['test_0.nc', 'test_1.nc', 'test_2.nc', 'test_3.nc']

    parameter_tuples = [
        (files[0], 0),
        (files[1], 1),
        (files[2], 2),
        (files[3], 3)
    ]

    # write to arr from different processes
    with closing(mp.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(shared_arr,))) as p:
        # many processes access different slices of the same array
        p.map_async(g, parameter_tuples)
    p.join()

    print(arr_orig)
    print(tonumpyarray(shared_arr, np.float32).reshape(N, M))


def init(shared_arr_):
    global shared_arr
    shared_arr = shared_arr_  # must be inherited, not passed as an argument


def tonumpyarray(mp_arr, dtype=np.float64):
    return np.frombuffer(mp_arr.get_obj(), dtype)


def g(params):
    """no synchronization."""
    print("Current File Name: ", params[0])

    tmp_dataset = xr.open_dataset(params[0])

    print(tmp_dataset["x"].data[:])

    arr = tonumpyarray(shared_arr)
    arr[params[1], :] = tmp_dataset["x"].data[:]

    tmp_dataset.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    main()
```

Comment: Have you seen the xarray documentation on using dask for parallel computing: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html ? At first glance, your problem seems to be handled using dask.

Comment: I would definitely recommend Dask instead. If you really need shared memory multiprocessing, try [Plasma](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/08/08/plasma-in-memory-object-store/).

Comment: @jhamman I am aware of Dask, and I have used it in the past. However, I don't think that the validation routines I am using now are best suited for Dask, as they require a lot of loops. So I have already written some routines to speed up the loops in parallel (with Numba), but the I/O takes a long time with my current program. So I'm trying to speed that up, and since I have a lot of files to read I figured multiprocessing would be a good way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's wrong?

1.You forgot to reshape back after `tonumpyarray`.
2.You used the wrong `dtype` in `tonumpyarray`.

## Code

```
import ctypes
import logging
import multiprocessing as mp
import xarray as xr

from contextlib import closing

import numpy as np

info = mp.get_logger().info


def main():

    data = np.arange(10)

    for i in range(4):
        ds = xr.Dataset({'x': data})
        ds.to_netcdf('test_{}.nc'.format(i))

        ds.close()


    logger = mp.log_to_stderr()
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # create shared array
    N, M = 4, 10
    shared_arr = mp.Array(ctypes.c_float, N * M)
    arr = tonumpyarray(shared_arr, dtype=np.float32)
    arr = arr.reshape((N, M))

    # Fill with random values
    arr[:, :] = np.zeros((N, M))
    arr_orig = arr.copy()

    files = ['test_0.nc', 'test_1.nc', 'test_2.nc', 'test_3.nc']

    parameter_tuples = [
        (files[0], 0),
        (files[1], 1),
        (files[2], 2),
        (files[3], 3)
    ]

    # write to arr from different processes
    with closing(mp.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(shared_arr, N, M))) as p:
        # many processes access different slices of the same array
        p.map_async(g, parameter_tuples)
    p.join()

    print(arr_orig)
    print(tonumpyarray(shared_arr, np.float32).reshape(N, M))


def init(shared_arr_, N_, M_):    # add shape
    global shared_arr
    global N, M
    shared_arr = shared_arr_  # must be inherited, not passed as an argument
    N = N_
    M = M_


def tonumpyarray(mp_arr, dtype=np.float32):  # change type
    return np.frombuffer(mp_arr.get_obj(), dtype)


def g(params):
    """no synchronization."""
    print("Current File Name: ", params[0])

    tmp_dataset = xr.open_dataset(params[0])

    print(tmp_dataset["x"].data[:])

    arr = tonumpyarray(shared_arr).reshape(N, M)   # reshape
    arr[params[1], :] = tmp_dataset["x"].data[:]

    tmp_dataset.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    main()
```

Comment: This was it, it didn't throw an error so I couldn't find it.