# Multiprocessing a function's output to a single array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multiprocessing

I have been trying this for quite sometime now, but my array remains unchanged.

My array here is `TC_p_value`, and the function I am trying to simulate is `TC_stats`. The code runs fine if we run it normally, but takes too long to simulate (about an hour). Thus, to reduce the processing time, I divided the original array (1000x100) in 10 small sets of 100x100. Although, the code runs without an error, I somehow always get the same array (same as it is defined originally). I tried to define `TC_p_value` as `global`, so that each run can assign values to specific part of the array. However, it seems like I am doing something wrong here (as simulating a single array on multiple processors is not possible) or is there something wrong with my coding logic?

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Code for the same is written below.

```
import pingouin as pg # A package to do regression
TC_p_value = np.zeros((Treecover.shape[1],Treecover.shape[2])) #let this array be of size 1000 x 100

def TC_stats(grid_start):
    global TC_p_value
    for lat in tqdm(range(grid_start, grid_start+100)):
        for lon in range(Treecover.shape[2]):
            TC_p_value[lat,lon] = pg.corr(y=Treecover[:, lat,lon].values,
                                  x=np.arange(1,16,1))['p-val'].values[0]

#Multiprocessing starts here
from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    grid = np.arange(0,1000,100) #Running it in a group of 100, 10 times
    pool.map(TC_stats, grid)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'empty array'?  Something about the shape?  Or just that the values of `TC_p_value` remain unchanged (0)?  'empty' is a vague term when dealing in `numpy` arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for pointing it out. Empty array would be a wrong terminology. What you guessed is correct, it remains an unchanged 'zero' array. I'll correct this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an array defined globally is not shared across processes. Thus, you need to use shared memory.

```py
import ctypes
import numpy as np
import pingouin as pg # A package to do regression

N, M = Treecover.shape[1], Treecover.shape[2]
mp_arr = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, N * M)
TC_p_value = np.frombuffer(mp_arr.get_obj())
TC_p_value = TC_p_value.reshape((N, M))
#let this array be of size 1000 x 100

def TC_stats(grid_start):
    TC_p_value = np.frombuffer(mp_arr.get_obj())
    TC_p_value = TC_p_value.reshape((N, M))
    for lat in tqdm(range(grid_start, grid_start+100)):
        for lon in range(Treecover.shape[2]):
            TC_p_value[lat,lon] = pg.corr(y=Treecover[:, lat,lon].values,
                                  x=np.arange(1,16,1))['p-val'].values[0]

def init(shared_arr_):
    global mp_arr
    mp_arr = shared_arr_

#Multiprocessing starts here
from multiprocessing import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(initializer=init, initargs=(mp_arr,))
    grid = np.arange(0,1000,100) #Running it in a group of 100, 10 times
    pool.map_async(TC_stats, grid)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I ran the code above with some modified toy example, and it worked.

Reference: [Use numpy array in shared memory for multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing)