# How to keep Processes alive in python multiprocessing so that they maintain state and can be reused?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I would like to divide an expensive computation among many subprocesses that can all work on part of the problem in an embarassing parallel way. However, each subprocess needs a large amount of initial data (different for each subprocess). I would like to pass in this initial data only once when the processes are created and then be able to call each subprocess multiple times to do work with different arguments (but always with the same initial data).

I feel like this should be a very common situation but I can't figure out how to do it.

A concrete example:

```
class MyWorker:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data #this is a large array
    def dosomework(self, arg):
        #does some work using self.data and the arg
        #arg is cheap to pickle and send from the main process, data is not
        return result

datachunks = [hugearray[i:i+chunksize] for i in range(0, len(hugearray), chunksize)] #break up huge array into chunks

# I want to create a bunch of new process and in each process initialize a MyWorker object with a different chunk of the data.
workers = [MyWorker(chunk) for chunk in datachunks] # These all live in the main process (not what I want)

# Now I want to call the workers' dosomework method in parallel many times with different args.
argstodo = [1,2,3,4,5]
results = []

for arg in argstodo:
    r = [worker.dosomework(arg) for worker in workers] #want the workers to run in parallel in their own processes
    results.append(r)
```

I can create all the MyWorkers in the main process and then create a `multiprocessing.Pool`. Then I can use `pool.map` and pass in each worker's `dosomework` function along with a corresponding `arg`. Something like:

```
def apply(x):
    func, args = x
    return func(args)

with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
    for arg in argstodo:
        r = pool.map(apply, [(worker,arg) for worker in workers])
        results.append(r)
```

But this seems extremely inefficient since the workers' `self.data` has to be pickled and unpickled over and over again.

Comment: I think you need to use a [multiprocessing queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) to do that well. The idea is to send data to the queue so user retrieve the infos. Then they keep the data sent and you can send the argument after that without sending the initial data again. This is a bit cumbersome to use and manual but AFAIK this is the standard way to do it (multiprocessing managers may be an alternative solution which is as efficient and uglier IMHO).

Comment: If `hugearray` is a numpy array or something similar, you can use shared memory between processes. See e. g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing

Answer (score 2):

It seems like maybe you think you need to instantiate a process every time you want to execute the function with a different arg. You just need to create a worker that has an indefinite run loop.

I would recommend utilizing something like the following pattern --

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class DataWorker(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, data, daemon=True):
        super().__init__(daemon=daemon)
        self.data = data #this is a large array
        self.queue = mp.Queue()
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            while not self.queue.empty():
                arg = self.queue.get()
                # Perform some computation using the arg
        
            time.sleep(0.5) # Avoid unnecessary clock cycles

worker_data = "" # Large data object

# Instantiate and start 4 worker processes
worker_dict = {i:DataWorker(data=worker_data) for i in range(4)}
for idx, worker in worker_dict.items():
    worker.start()

# Putting an item in the workers queue will cause it to run
worker[0].queue.put(arg)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using semaphores to control the behavior of the workers. Checking the empty status of a queue is sometimes not entirely reliable due to a small delay before the status changes. Semaphores also avoid polling the queue constantly as it utilizes blocking until something is available. But it can still exit the loop in a clean way.

As @Teeya Bruno 's answer is already pretty nice, I just update that one

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

class DataWorker(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, data, daemon=True):
        super().__init__(daemon=daemon)
        self.data = data #this is a large array
        self.queue = mp.Queue()
    
    def run(self):
            for arg in iter(self.queue.get, "STOP"):  
            # blocks until something available, exits when receiving "STOP"

                # Perform some computation using the arg
           
worker_data = "" # Large data object

# Instantiate and start 4 worker processes
worker_dict = {i:DataWorker(data=worker_data) for i in range(4)}
for idx, worker in worker_dict.items():
    worker.start()

# Putting an item in the workers queue will cause it to run
worker[0].queue.put(arg)

# too finalize all workers you would
for x in range(4):
    worker[x].queue.put("STOP")
for x in range(4):
    worker[x].join()
```