How do you parallelize access to a shared array in python using concurrent.futures?
I have the following piece of code to illustrate my problem:
Each thread calculates a value locs and then updates the result array, assume that that update (result[locs] += mask[locs] ) is a very slow operation, how can I parallelize it so it can be threaded too?
import numpy as np
import time
import concurrent.futures

MAX  = 100
SIZE = 500
mask = np.random.randint(0, MAX, (SIZE, SIZE))

def process_image(i):
    start = time.time()
    locs = np.where(mask > i)
    print(f"    process_image({i}) took {round(time.time() - start, 2)} secs.")
    return locs

if __name__ == '__main__':

    result = np.zeros((SIZE, SIZE))
     
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=32) as executor:
            results = [executor.submit(process_image, i) for i in range(MAX) ]
            for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
                locs = f.result()         
                # How do I parallelize this operation? Where the result of each thread updates a shared result array
                result[locs] += mask[locs] 

    print(result)


If possible, try ProcessPoolExecutor?

See here?

@user24714692 then it won't work on the same array because you will be using multiple processes. You can share numpy arrays across processes, but in that code, that won't happen

@user24714692 no. You are using multiple processes, so each process has it's own numpy array.

@juanpa.arrivillaga I see. What's the solution? Answer the question?

Something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894791/use-numpy-array-in-shared-memory-for-multiprocessing which could probably serve as a duplicate for this question

although, I'm assuming threading was used here for a reason because there is some I/O bound task

You're using multithreading and therefore the results ndarray is naturally available to all threads.
However, the result[locs] += mask[locs] may not be thread-safe. Therefore you would need to defend the result object using a Lock.
I assume that your implementation of process_image() does some I/O in reality then you could make the following changes:
import numpy as np
import time
import concurrent.futures
from threading import Lock

MAX  = 100
SIZE = 500
mask = np.random.randint(0, MAX, (SIZE, SIZE))
LOCK = Lock()

def process_image(i):
    start = time.time()
    locs = np.where(mask > i)
    print(f"    process_image({i}) took {round(time.time() - start, 2)} secs.")
    with LOCK:
         result[locs] += mask[locs]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    result = np.zeros((SIZE, SIZE))
     
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process_image, range(MAX))

    print(result)

