# Pickle error on code for converting numpy array into shared memory array

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, pickle

Trying to use the code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15390953/378594 to convert a numpy array into a shared memory array and back. Running the following code:

`shared_array = shmarray.ndarray_to_shm(my_numpy_array)`

and then passing the shared_array as an argument in the list of argument for a multiprocessing pool:

`pool.map(my_function, list_of_args_arrays)`

Where `list_of_args_arrays` contains my shared array and other arguments.

It results in the following error

`PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_double_Array_<array size>'>: attribute lookup multiprocessing.sharedctypes.c_double_Array_<array size> failed`

Where `<array_size>` is the linear size of my numpy array.

I guess something has changed in numpy ctypes or something like that?

## Further details:

I only need access to shared information. No editing will be done by the processes.

The function that calls the pool lies within a class. The class is initiated and the function is called by a main.py file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently when using `multiprocessing.Pool` all arguments are pickled, and so there was no use using `multiprocessing.Array`. Changing the code so that it uses an array of processes did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things: 
There is no need to pickle arrays (especially if they are read only):

you just need to do keep them accessible through some global variable:

**(known to work in linux, but may not work in windows, don't know)**

```
import numpy as np,multiprocessing as mp
class si:
  arrs=None

def summer(i):
    return si.arrs[i].sum()

def main():
    si.arrs=[np.zeros(100) for _ in range(1000)]
    pool = mp.Pool(16)
    res=pool.map(summer,range(1000))
    print res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If your arrays need to be read and written, you need to use this: 
[Is shared readonly data copied to different processes for Python multiprocessing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549190/is-shared-readonly-data-copied-to-different-processes-for-python-multiprocessing/5550156#5550156)

Comment: This looks good. Can you add how it's supposed to look like if the file is imported and there is no `if __name__ == '__main':` and `main()`. What is the important element here, that the global variable and the function `summer` are in the same scope? Or maybe the definition of the pool and the global variables?

Comment: The important thing is to have a global resource initialized before mp.Pool().
E.g. main() and '_ _main_ _' could be in other file (say sumfile.py)
Just in main() instead of si.arr it will be 
sumfile.si.arr=[]
and instead of pool.map(summer..) it'll be
pool.map(sumfile.summer,...)

Comment: Strange, I'm updating the global variables stored in class, and this update is done before calling Pool(), but still the processes spawned behave as though I did not change the global variables at all - they see the default value (i.e. `None`) despite the value is indeed changed in the main program process...

Comment: Also take a look here http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows. It seems to contradict your example

Comment: I guess if you are using windows that may not work (their process spawning is different), but I never had windows to try it.