# Can I send char* with sigqueue to another process

Tags: c, signals, sigqueue

Here is a part of my code in client program

```
      union sigval toServer;   

      char *test = "dummy";
      serverPID = atol(buf2);
      toServer.sival_ptr = (void *)test;


      // Register to server
      if (sigqueue(serverPID, SIGUSR1, toServer) == -1) {  // register
         fprintf(stderr," Server isn't ready!\n");
         return 1;
      }
```

Here is my handler in server program

```
      static void register_handler(int signo, siginfo_t* info, void *context) {   

      registeredProgramID = info->si_pid;

      if(info->si_value.sival_ptr != NULL)
       fprintf(stderr," sent value is  = %s \n" ,(char *)info->si_value.sival_ptr);
      }
```

There is no error but i can't get what i sent. It prints something weird.

Comment: How do you create server and client processes?

Comment: on same pc and 2 terminals   gcc -c server.c
                             gcc -o serv server.o
                             ./serv   same for client

Comment: You are passing pointer to string between process. The string data is allocated in client's address space and this pointer isn't valid in server's address space (it may be, if one process is spawned by the other using `fork`, however, I see that it is not the case). You should use other IPC, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404604/comparing-unix-linux-ipc) question.

Comment: Hmmmm i see. Thank you :). fifo was my second option . I thought this one was easier .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot.

You can send `char*`, but the receiving process normally doesn't normally have access to the memory of the sending process and the memory may be mapped differently. When you access the memory address pointed to by the received pointer the result is undefined (i.e. platform specific and not necessarily repeatable).
The most likely result is either some kind of memory protection error or that the read memory contains a random value.