# How to detect and communicate with another process under Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, mpi, ipc, multiprocess

I have a program 'P' and P is executed in terminal A. Let's call it process A. While process A is running, terminal B is opened and executes P as process B.

How can I make process A find process B and exchange data with each other? Someone told me to implement it with MPI but I haven't found any material telling me how.

I also appreciate that if anyone can tell me how to make these two process read and write the same variable (same address in memory). This solves my problem, too.

Comment: My program is written in C++. Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: Look up shared memory.

Comment: There are many many ways to exchange data between processes. You need to specify your requirements more clearly in order to figure out the appropriate methods in your case. What are the processes doing? How are they interacting with the user? How much data needs to be transferred?

Comment: Unix-domain sockets, message queues, and shared memory are the easiest methods to use for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which Linux IPC technique to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2281204/608639), [Comparing Unix/Linux IPC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/404604/608639), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [lots of options](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node7.html), but in most cases I think you'll find that named pipes/fifo will meet your needs.

See [mkfifo](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo), which creates a named pipe on the filesystem; that pipe can then be opened and accessed using standard open/read/write like a file for interprocess communications.